# image viewer (on-demand from gallery) for presentations

Tags: linux, osx, presentation, image-viewer

I need to do slideshows with a projector, used FastStone for it, now looking for a similar app on Linux or OS X. The audience should not see the gallery and you messing around with it, only one image at a time with black around it. Zooming and panning should be part of the functionality, but distracting menus etc. should not be visible, best if keyboard-driven.

Comment: Does the software have to run on both, Mac OS X *and* Ubuntu, or is it okay if only one of these OS is supported?

Comment: I'm looking for both, maybe two separate apps. The reason is that I've had certain projectors/televisions confusing the Mac (lack of proper driver) so I had to pull in Ubuntu which worked just fine, except for the lack of proper presentation software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [qView](https://intvhq.com/qview/)

- Runs on macOS, Linux, and Windows
- Has no GUI visible in fullscreen mode
- Has keyboard shortcuts for all common functions